# How to run tests using maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I run the command mvn test in my java project, it shows 0 tests run. There is a single test file under src/test/java named xyzTest.java  Although I can go to it and right-click on the Test file inside Intellij Idea and run all the tests in the file.
I was wondering how I could do the same in the command line.
Currently, there are only dependencies in the pom.xml I am not using any plugins. I read that the surefire maven plugin could help with this. But I find it strange to have to add a plugin to execute such a simple thing. How does IntelliJ run it when one right-clicks on the file and runs it?
Is there an alternative or any way to run all the tests?
I am able to run the main file through using the command line by executing mvn exec:java

Comment: Show us your test file.

Comment: You'll need to add the surefire plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add the Surefire plugin. From the [Maven Surefire Plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/): "The Surefire Plugin is used during the test phase of the build lifecycle to execute the unit tests of an application."

From the [Usages](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/usage.html#usage) page:
"Best practice is to define the version of the Surefire Plugin that you want to use in either your pom.xml or a parent pom.xml:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

The Surefire Plugin can be invoked by calling the test phase of the build lifecycle.

```
mvn test
```

"
You can run `mvn test` if you want to run Maven phases up to and including test, or `mvn clean verify` if you want to rebuild and test your project.

While I understand you might find it strange to have to add a plugin to execute such a simple thing, this is how Maven works. From the [Maven documentation on Plugins](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html): "Maven is - at its heart - a plugin execution framework; all work is done by plugins."

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn test
```

If you are executing goal and trying to generate report this may help you.

```
<build>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                        <include>**/Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/TestCase.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*Abstract*Test.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Answer (score -2):

When you run

```
mvn clean install
```

all test will be excecuted

Answer (score -2):

You can Use This command and run a Test
mvn clean install -U -DskipTests=false